# SequenceWriter wrap in array not working Jackson

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, deserialization, file-writing

I have the following method which writes list of objects and jsons into a file. However while writing to the file, it converts the objects into a json array like:

```
[{ "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2" } { "field1" : "value3", "field2" : "value4" }]
```

I want it like every object in new line without being wrapped with braces:

```
{ "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2" }
{ "field1" : "value3", "field2" : "value4" }
```

Java method:

```
public File convertObjectListToJSONFile(@NonNull List<Object> objectsList, @NonNull String fileName, Class clazz){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectWriter objectWriter = mapper.writer();
    File file = null;
    String filePath = TEMP_DIRECTORY.concat(fileName);
    try {
        file = new File(filePath);
        SequenceWriter writer = objectWriter.writeValues(file);
        writer.writeAll(objectsList);
    } catch (IOException ioexception) {
        log.error("Exception while creating file for object for fileName: {}, class {}", fileName, clazz.toString());
        throw new RuntimeException(ioexception);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `MinimalPrintWriter` with new line as configured root value separator to achieve the above.

```java
public <E> void serializeAsStream(
        @NotNull final List<E> objects, @NotNull final File filePath
) throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writer(new MinimalPrintWriter("\n"))
        .writeValues(filePath)
        .writeAll(objects)
        .close();
}
```